# How to add a redirect to https?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I already have a redirect to the main page of the site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But if you type `domain.com`, then the redirection will be to `example.com/index.php` But I need to redirect immediately to `https://example.com/index.php`

Comment: **FYI:** Most hosting providers allow you to set this up in the CPanel relatively easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```